# Read multiple json files from blob storage to dataframe using pyspark in databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I am trying to get all the json files stored in a single container in a subfolder in blob storage. I have setup the environment in databricks and have the connection linked. Currently I am using this code

```
df = spark.read.json("wasbs://container_name@blob_storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/sub_folder/*.json")
```

but I am getting just the first file and not all the json files present in the subfolder even after including the wildcard `/*.json`.

I am trying to get all the files from the subfolder in a single dataframe and store as a table in sql database.

Can someone assist on what I am missing.

Comment: it looks good to me. How do you know it read only one file?

Comment: @pltc because it's showing just the first file data when I use df.display(). Is there better way to check if I have the data for all the files?

Comment: huh, display only shows an limited amount of data. Did you try querying the data?

Comment: databricks only display first 1000 records. You should counting instead

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in my environment.

I have 3 json blob files inside the subfolder of my container in storage account. I am able to read all the blob json files in a single data frame

[image]

You can use the below code to display all json the files from the subfolder in a single data frame

```
df = spark.read.json("wasbs://container_name@blob_storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/sub_folder/*.json")
df.show()
```

[image]